# Mostrar Layout al hacer Click en item de RecyclerView

Tags: android

Estoy utilizando un `RecyclerView` para mostrar una `lista` de `usuarios`. Y me gustaría que al hacer `click` en los `items` de la `lista` se lance un `layout` mostrandome la información que tengo guardada en mi `bd` del `usuario` seleccionado, sin iniciar una nueva `actividad`. Comparto el código a ver si pueden ayudarme.

MiCuadroDeDialogo

```
public class MiCuadroDeDialogo extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_usuario, null);
    builder.setView(v);

    return builder.create();
}
}
```

UsuarioPendiente

```
public class UsuarioPendiente extends AppCompatActivity {

Context context;
LinearLayout volver;
RecyclerView listaPendientes;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_usuario_pendiente);
    context = UsuarioPendiente.this;
    volver = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnVolverPendientes);


    listaPendientes = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listaPendientes);
    listaPendientes.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    listaPendientes.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    ControladorUsuario controlador = new ControladorUsuario(context);
    final UsuarioAdapter adapter = new UsuarioAdapter(context, controlador.listaUsuarios());
    listaPendientes.setAdapter(adapter);



    volver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

UsuarioAdapter

```
public class UsuarioAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsuarioHolder> implements Filterable {

Context c;
public ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios, listaFiltrada;
FiltroUsuarios filtro;



   public UsuarioAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios){
   this.c=ctx;
   this.usuarios=usuarios;
   this.listaFiltrada=usuarios;


 }

@Override
public UsuarioHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_lista_usuarios,null);

    //HOLDER
    UsuarioHolder holder=new UsuarioHolder(v);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UsuarioHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.nombre.setText(usuarios.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.apellido.setText(usuarios.get(position).getApellido());
    holder.bind(usuarios.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return usuarios.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filtro==null){
        filtro = new FiltroUsuarios(listaFiltrada, this);
    }
    return filtro;
}

}
```

UsuarioHolder

```
public class UsuarioHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView nombre, apellido;
public LinearLayout linearLayoutItem;



public UsuarioHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    this.apellido = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreUsuario);
    this.nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.apellidoUsuario);

    linearLayoutItem = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutItem);

}

 public void bind(Usuario user) {
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       /* como lanzo el cuadro de dialogo correctamente aqui*/



        }
    });

}
```

dialog_usuario.xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En que layout quieres mostrar la información?

Comment: se debría ejecutar dentro de `UsuarioPendiente` que es la clase q contiene el `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza un AlertDialog que es mas sencillo. Para eso tienes que utilizar AlertDialog.Builder y asignarle los parametros que necesites, en este caso `setView(view)` y show() para mostrar el dialogo.

Primero hay que enviarle el contexto a `UsuarioHolder` ya que `AlertDialog.Builder` requiere del contexto en el constructor:

```
//...
@Override
public UsuarioHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_lista_usuarios,null);

    // inicia el holder y envia el contexto en el constructor
    return new UsuarioHolder(v, this.c);;
}
//...
```

Ahora hay que definir que `UsuarioHolder` reciba el contexto en el constructor:

```
public class UsuarioHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //...
    private Context context;
    public UsuarioHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
        //...

        this.context = context;
    }
```

Entonces ahora en el metodo onClick se pone el codigo donde mostraras el dialog:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // inflamos el layout   
        View view = getActivity()
        .getLayoutInflater()
        .inflate(R.layout.dialog_usuario, null);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(view)
        .show();

        //utilizando view, puedesa acceder a los controles del layout dialog_usuario
        TextView username = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.idDeUnControl);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Prodrias abrir un AlertDialog con una vista personalizada que te muestra esta información, algo asi.

Primero asigna el evento onClick a tus elementos en el recyclerview utilizando un metodo en tu holder por ejemplo:

```
public void bind(Usuario user) { itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { /* aqui creas tu alertdialog */ });
```

este metodo lo ejecutas en el metodo onBindViewHolder

```
holder.bind(usuarios.get(position));
```

pasas el objeto usuario para que recuperes esos datos en el metodo bind y los pintes en tu alertdialog

Comment: Realice modificaciones pero sigo sin poder mostrar mi `dialog_usuario` ya q siempre me consigo caer en errores.